# ...thus development on these once flagship products "has stalled" or "have stalled"?

Tags: grammatical-number, american-english, verb-agreement

The following sentence is being flagged in Microsoft Word as incorrect grammar:

> More recently however, [Lint and Splint] tools have been superseded by
>   a now robust field of static language analysis tools which work for
>   many languages, and thus development on these once flagship products
>   **has stalled**.

Word says that it should be "have stalled", rather than "has stalled". I understand that it is plural, but is 'development' a special case as it is a rather abstract verb?

It simply sounds wrong to say "have stalled".

Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Word does not appear to understand that the subject of "has stalled" is "**development** on these once flagship products". It seems to think that the subject is "flagship products" (plural) instead of their development (singular). Hence the erroneous suggestion to use "have stalled" instead of "has stalled". "Has stalled" is correct.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. It made me second guess myself because of the fact that there are technically two development processes that operated separately. Again, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Please don't answer questions unsuitable for a site devoted to linguists.